# Unable to use HTML content on bootstrap-notify plugin

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap-notify plugin to display notifications. It can be found at [Bootstap-Notify](http://goodybag.github.io/bootstrap-notify/). However I am unable to use html option as per what is specified. If I turn HTML option on the notification comes without any message. I appreciate any help with this.Thanks

Here's the function that displays the message (at a specified time, it works fine, but just with text)

```
    function notifyMessage(position, messageIn, dd,mm,yyyy,hh,mn)
{
    //add the timestamp to the message
//        var message1 = '<html>Scheduled - '+dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy+' '+hh+':'+mn+'<br>'+ message + '</html>';
    var message1 = '<html>Scheduled - '+ messageIn + '</html>';
    alert (message1.html());
    //hardcoded blackgloss type, this can be made a parameter if required
    var type = 'blackgloss';
    var now = new Date();  
    var millisTillTime = new Date(yyyy, mm-1, dd, hh, mn, 00, 0) - now; //ms till the specified time
    //set millisTillTime to 0 incase its value < 0 (to display expired undisplayed messages)
    if(millisTillTime < 0)
    {
        millisTillTime = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(function()
    {
            $('.' + position).notify({ message: { text: message1}, type: type, fadeOut: {enabled: false}}).show();
    }, millisTillTime);
}
```

Now, if I change the line `message: { text: message1}` to `message: { html: true, text: message1}`, the message goes blank.

My main page is here

```
<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Notify CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap-notify.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Styles -->
<link href="css/styles/alert-bangtidy.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles/alert-blackgloss.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div class='notifications top-right'></div>
<div class='notifications bottom-right'></div>
<div class='notifications top-left'></div>
<div class='notifications bottom-left'></div>
<script src="../../javascripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
<? include 'notify.php';?>
</body>
```

The actual plugin can be found at [Bootstap-Notify](http://goodybag.github.io/bootstrap-notify/)

Comment: show us what you have done so far we can't help you otherwise

Comment: I have added code as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/HSQE7/

I set the html property to message1

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

```js
function notifyMessage(position, messageIn, dd,mm,yyyy,hh,mn) {
  //add the timestamp to the message
  var message1 = '<strong style="color: blue">'
      + 'Scheduled - '
      + messageIn
      + '</strong>';
  //hardcoded blackgloss type, this can be made a parameter if required
  var type = 'blackgloss';
  var now = new Date();  
  var millisTillTime = new Date(yyyy, mm-1, dd, hh, mn, 00, 0) - now; //ms till the specified time
  //set millisTillTime to 0 incase its value < 0 (to display expired undisplayed messages)
  if(millisTillTime < 0) millisTillTime = 0;
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.' + position).notify({ message: { html: message1}, type: type, fadeOut: {enabled: false}}).show();
  }, millisTillTime);
}

notifyMessage('test', 'hello', 3, 2, 2014, 11, 53);
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit @idefine, I just figured that probably 5 seconds before you post, while reading the example and the notify.js file (line 41,42). Again, I really appreciate your help.